# Implementing SproutCore-like bindings in a JavaScript Web application

Tags: javascript, binding, sproutcore

I've done the [SproutCore tutorial](http://wiki.sproutcore.com/Todos%C2%A0Intro) and have an idea of what the framework has to offer. It seems amazing, although I'm not sure how I feel about a framework which generates the HTML and CSS behind the scenes. The thing about SproutCore which I find most appealing is its bindings – reducing the amount of glue code required to keep everything in sync can only be a good thing.

I'm interested in learning about how SproutCore's bindings are implemented. I would love to be able to take advantage of bindings without necessarily using a framework such as SproutCore.

How would one go about writing the JavaScript code necessary to bind data and their representations, to have views instantly reflect changes to the data without any glue code?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why don't you want the HTML and CSS generated for you?

Comment: Some of us still have flashbacks to the good ol days of Frontpage and Dreamweaver. Maybe things have improved since then, but I'll still write my own damn HTML/CSS/Javascript tyvm.

Comment: Well with SC you actually do have quite a bit of control. You can actually micro-manage the HTML/CSS if you want to instead of relying on SC to do it for you. However SC does a good job of managing this and in most cases it's a huge time-saver. However, SC isn't the right tool for every job, so there are still cases where you should just write straight HTML with a bit of JS mixed in.

Comment: I do very much like the idea of SproutCore generating the HTML and CSS. I'm just a little uneasy at this stage as the framework is totally new to me so feels like a mysterious black box. As I gain an understanding of what's going on behind the scenes I'll feel more comfortable.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Unfortunately the SC documentation is a bit lacking. However the community is very helpful. Try the IRC chatroom #sproutcore or the mailing list: sproutcore@googlegroups.com. There's also a new version on SC that should be released in the very near future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With SproutCore using the 'get' and 'set' methods provided by the [SC.Observable](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Observable.html#constructor) mixin enables key-value observing. When you create a binding it basically sets up an observer that fires when the 'set' method is called on the value it's observing and then propagates the change. When a binding is tied to a view on your page, the binding invokes the necessary view code to make the changes to the DOM. You could take a look at API docs and source for [SC.Observable](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Observable.html#constructor) and [SC.Binding](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.Binding.html#constructor) over at http://docs.sproutcore.com.

Since SproutCore is divided into multiple "frameworks", you could just take the framework where this core stuff lives, called 'runtime', and use it in your project without all of the data store and view layers that you don't want. You could also try to reproduce this functionality yourself, but I wonder if you'd end up having to reproduce much of what they've created.

Comment: Terrific answer! Thanks, bruz. :)